# Google sheets search for blank cell, then import value of cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have data coming from a Google sheet.  I want to search the cell and if it is blank, insert N/A into another cell, but if it is not blank, insert the text that is in the cell to the other cell. I am sure it is simple to do, but I cannot figure it out.  Your help is appreciated. 
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cdBa.png)

Comment: You are expected to post your current `code` effort within your question because otherwise, you are unlikely to get any answers. (just the way it works here)

Comment: Take a look at the IF function, and give it a try. There are lots of examples available. It works the same as Excel, so you can look at those examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Say A1 is either blank or a value that you want to test, and B1 is the cell to either put the value of A1, or N/A if A1 is blank.

In that case, try putting this formula in B1:

```
=if(isblank(A1),NA(),A1)
```

if() tests if the first argument is true for false. If it's true, the second argument comes out. If it's false, the third value comes out.

isblank() returns true if the cell referenced is blank, and false if the cell contains some value.

NA() throws the N/A error.

For future reference, it helps to put more specific references in your question if you can, instead of leaving it general and vague.